# Ajax to php file error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting a very generic error message from an Ajax calls `xhr` parameter

```
readyState 0
responseText ""
statusText "error"
```

The rest are all `function()` or `function(e)` or `function(e,t)`

I know the issue can't be a domain based error as I'm calling the same server and it's local
Here is the script:

```
    $(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            timeout: 100000 //Time in milliseconds
        });
       loadTest();
    });

    function loadTest(){
        //var postValues=null;

        $.post("pieTest.Json.php")

            .done(function(data){
                console.log("pi: "+data.pie+" Time: "+data.sequentialTime)
            })
            .fail(function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown){
                console.log(xhr);
            })


    }
```

---

here is the text from thte file that it's calling (called pieTest.Json.php:

---

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/php/init.php");



$result = array();
set_time_limit ( 200 );


try {
    $startT = time();
    $result['pie']      = pie(100000);


    $endT = time();

    $result['sequentialTime']=$endT-$startT;
    $result['seqStart']=$startT;
    $result['endTime']=$endT;
}catch(DisplayableException $e){
    $result['status']       = "fail";
    $result['errorMessage'] = $e->getMessage();
}catch (exception $e){
    $result['status']       = "fail";
    $result['errorMessage'] =$e->getMessage();
    inspect($e);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
function pie ($n)
{
    if ($n==1)
        return 4*1;
    else
        return ( 4*(pow(-1,$n+1)*(1/(2*$n-1))) + pie($n-1) );
}
```

---

I'm attempting to use the pie function to test sequential vs some parrallel styles in php. But when I ratchet up the parameter being passed into pie around 21999 I get that error. Before that I get a value for pi and a time of 0 (which seems low for the diff and is why I want to raise the speed so I can get the diff between a seq and parallel solution).

Comment: 22751 seems to be the highest parameter that I can pass without the above error

Comment: Why do you put a set_time_limit (200) ? It will stop the execution before your code returning

Comment: The default for the server is 30, so I set it to 200 to make sure the server wasn't timing it out.